# How do I find compatible motherboard for my computer?

Tags: motherboard, compatibility

I have a Dell Optiplex GX270 that recently stopped working, and I suspect a motherboard (I can go into why if needed).  I want to get a replacement from eBay or the like, but I'm not sure what to get.  I know that I have the mini-Tower form factor.  If I look for "Dell GX270 motherboard" on eBay I find multiple model numbers (or a number I assume is a model number).  I believe I have found mine (U1325).

I suspect I don't have to get the exact same motherboard, I just need to get something that fits my form factor and is compatible with the type of RAM I have (probably not an issue as I suspect all GX270s use the same type of RAM).

So, my questions are
1)  Is any motherboard okay as long as it fits the criteria of form factor and model number? 
2)  If not, is there a good way (i.e. website) to determine what model numbers are compatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dell are notorious for having cases and motherboards that go together.  Although you have a mini tower, it's a dell mini tower, so a standard layout motherboard won't fit.  It's even dodgy whether a motherboard from a different Optiplex would fit your case.

For safety I'd get the exact same model motherboard as the one you have.

Comment: While most likely true in his case, the downside is that it's probably a custom Dell motherboard and you will be likely to pay several hundred dollars getting a replacement from Dell.  I would suggest getting a generic mid-tower and name brand motherboard that will work with the components your system has (CPU, HDD, RAM, etc).  You can usually buy a motherboard/case combo for cheaper than a replacement motherboard will cost from Dell.

Comment: Once I found the right model number, it was pretty easy to find multiple with the same number.